# cannot resolve context after importing android.content.Context; also

Tags: java, android, android-context

This is my `mainactivity.java` class

```
package com.example.apurva.therisingsatyam;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, LogIn.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to switch activity when the button is clicked.But as can be seen in above code there is a red line under context word at both the places in onClick method, although I have imported android.content.context . Please someone help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`context` is not declared and initialized

Change this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LogIn.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogIn.class);
```

Similarly for the other intent

Your MainActivity extends Activity

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

So to get context you can have `MainActivity.this`.

Also i don't see where you initiailze your views and your `Activity` does not implement `OnClickListener` interface

Comment: I am totally new to android. I am trying to make two buttons pointing to two different login and signup activity. I got this code online.Is there any problem in this code and plz tell me what do you mean by....."Also i don't see where you initialze your views and your Activity does not implement OnClickListener interface "

Comment: @apurvapathak do refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 1):

context is not declared by you, so I suggest you to use following lines of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogIn.class);//MainActivity.this contains your current context
startActivity(intent);
```

Still any doubt then feel free to ask.